# vertical navigation on hover change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am struggling to find a simple solution to create an div-navigation like this:
https://www.bueromoebel-experte.de/
[image]

The div with image on the right changes on hover of the left menu (and keeps the div, even if you go somewhere else with your mouse). But the left menu itself, when its clicked is linking to another page.

Must be sth like:

```
<ul>
<li> <a id="link1" href="example.de/abc" target="_blank">example 1</a></li>
<li> <a id="link2" href="example.de/def" target="_blank">example 2</a></li>
<li> <a id="link3" href="example.de/ghi" target="_blank">example 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="example1" class="hide"> Image, Text and Button</div>
<div id="example2" class="hide"> Image, Text and Button</div>
<div id="example3" class="hide"> Image, Text and Button</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide {
  position: absolute;
}
#example1 {
   z-index: 50;
}
#example3, #example2 {
   z-index: 10;
}
```

JS

```
$("HOVEREDLINK").hover(function() {
  $("HOVEREDLINK").css("z-index","70")
  $("ALLOTHERIDS").css("z-index","50")
});
```

As a beginner I am not quite sure how to do so or if it is a good solution. I would be really gratefull if you guys could help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: it would help you and other members looking to help if you can create code snippet or working example for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").onmouseover();
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```